# DNS config not applied after 48 hours

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind

I set name server to `ns1.mydomain.com` & `ns2.mydomain.com` in domain control panel. i configure my linux server with following :

```
/etc/bind$ cat named.conf.local 

zone "mydomain.com" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/mydomain.com.db";
}
```

and this is my domain configuration (mydomain.com.db file) :

```
/etc/bind$ cat mydomain.com.db 
;
; BIND data file for mydomain.com
;
$TTL    3h
@       IN      SOA     ns1.mydomain.com. email.mydomain.com. (
                          1        ; Serial
                          3h       ; Refresh after 3 hours
                          1h       ; Retry after 1 hour
                          1w       ; Expire after 1 week
                          1h )     ; Negative caching TTL of 1 day
;
@       IN      NS      ns1.mydomain.com.
@       IN      NS      ns2.mydomain.com.


mydomain.com.   IN      MX      10      mail.mydomain.com.
mydomain.com.   IN      A       my_valid_server_ip_here
ns1     IN      A       my_valid_server_ip_here
ns2     IN      A       my_valid_server_ip_here
www     IN      CNAME   mydomain.com.
mail        IN      A       my_valid_server_ip_here
ftp     IN      CNAME   mydomain.com.

; Subdomains
beta        IN  A   my_valid_server_ip_here
api     IN  A   my_valid_server_ip_here
```

and this is result of dig command

```
dig @my_valid_server_ip_here mydomain.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> @1my_valid_server_ip_here mydomain.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

I should waiting more or my configuration is wrong?

---- **UPDATED**

it's result of my ufw :

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
5432/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

53                         ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
```

------- **UPDATE** :
update rule, so new ufw status is

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: reject (incoming), allow (outgoing)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
5432/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
53                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
```

problem is exist, also dig can not resolve and throw same error!

Comment: Tell us the domain names involved or the help we can offer is very limited.

Comment: OK, both your domain's name servers seem to be `130.185.74.136`.  Leaving aside how bad an idea that is, is that your server (or a server under your control)?

Comment: yes it's my server, it's VPS.

Comment: OK, is your server's firewall admitting DNS queries, and is your server configured to answer questions for the internet-at-large about that domain?

Comment: dig does'nt resolve, please check firewall to your DNS server

Comment: @MadHatter I'm update question, i was added rule for port 53. what's goes wrong ?

Comment: @MojtabaAsg Unless I misunderstand your firewall rule only allows outbound? (`ALLOW OUT`)

Comment: I think that speaks for itself - consider changing that from `ALLOW OUT` to `ALLOW`.  The world needs to talk to your nameserver!

Comment: Thanks, i set that , and need wait for 24 hours again ?

Comment: @MojtabaAsg It should start working quickly if that is the only problem. Generally speaking, never blindly wait for 24 hours. Verify that everything works, then wait until it starts working for everyone.

Comment: `53                         ALLOW       Anywhere` rule added and `53                         ALLOW OUT      Anywhere` deleted. is  enough ? dig can not resolve yet same error that mentioned in question

Comment: You can't use ns1.bialesk.ir to the same domain.

Comment: @MadHatter I'm interested to know how you find my server ip when dns not set cauese firewall block dns port ?!

Comment: Please set up at GLUE record. This should solve this

Comment: `ns1     IN      A       130.185.74.136` `ns2     IN      A      130.185.74.136` I'm was added this lines for GLUE record.what's goes wrong ?

Comment: `dig ns bialesk.ir @a.nic.ir.` (which I think means your glue records are OK - I still think your DNS server isn't set to resolve for the Internet).

Comment: @MadHatter default is set to allow out so it's not necessary

Comment: I'm disable firewall completely and result is same. any suggestion ?

Comment: We've dealt with the firewall pretty well.  Please pay some more attention to the suggestions about named configuration.

Comment: @MadHatter you known my ip and domain, can you post answer for correct configuration ?

Comment: `allow-query             { any; } ;` if indeed that is the problem.  But *where* to put it in the maze of different BIND config files Ubuntu ships with is a problem you'll have to solve.

Comment: @MadHatter add that to related config file (/etc/bind/named.conf.options  - i'm using debian 8) and restart bind service , what's next now ?

Comment: @MojtabaAsg @MadHatter It's worth noting that `allow-query` actually defaults to allowing queries from any host unless you override it. However, `allow-query-cache` and `allow-recursion` have fairly sane defaults but will be also affected if you override `allow-query` alone (ie, leave those other ones unset). Ie, overriding `allow-query` alone first of all is probably pointless but it can also have severe consequences.  See http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#access_control for all the details on how these settings interact.

Comment: @MojtabaAsg since you've been kind enough to let TCP/53 in your firewall as well as UDP/53, I thought I'd try connecting (it being much easier to confirm a TCP connection remotely, than a UDP transaction).  No joy.  You're absolutely sure that bind is running on that server, listening on the public address?  Could we see the output of `netstat -an|grep -w 53` on the server?

Comment: @MadHatter it's empty. It's seem no body listen to port 53, but why when i even explicitly  start bind service ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Super Crazy Mistake !!**
No body listen to port 53, bind service doesn't run. so after run this command :

```
sudo named -g -p 53
```

i got this result :

```
11-Oct-2016 11:09:25.010 BIND 9 is maintained by Internet Systems Consortium,
11-Oct-2016 11:09:25.010 Inc. (ISC), a non-profit 501(c)(3) public-benefit 
11-Oct-2016 11:09:25.010 corporation.  Support and training for BIND 9 are 
11-Oct-2016 11:09:25.010 available at https://www.isc.org/support
11-Oct-2016 11:09:25.010 ----------------------------------------------------
11-Oct-2016 11:09:25.010 adjusted limit on open files from 65536 to 1048576
11-Oct-2016 11:09:25.010 found 1 CPU, using 1 worker thread
11-Oct-2016 11:09:25.010 using 1 UDP listener per interface
11-Oct-2016 11:09:25.010 using up to 4096 sockets
11-Oct-2016 11:09:25.012 loading configuration from '/etc/bind/named.conf'
11-Oct-2016 11:09:25.013 /etc/bind/named.conf:11: missing ';' before 'include'
11-Oct-2016 11:09:25.013 loading configuration: failure
11-Oct-2016 11:09:25.013 exiting (due to fatal error)
```

"Super Crazy Mistake" was happen !! I forgot put semicolon in zone configuration files so bind service doesn't even run.

```
zone "mydomain.com" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/mydomain.com.db";
};
```

after correct configuration and restart `bind9` service this is output of netstat for openports :

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      551/sshd        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3489/named      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      619/nginx -g daemon
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3489/named      
tcp        0      0 130.185.74.136:53       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3489/named      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3489/named      
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      551/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 ::1:953                 :::*                    LISTEN      3489/named      
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      619/nginx -g daemon
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      3489/named      
udp        0      0 172.17.0.1:53           0.0.0.0:*                           3489/named      
udp        0      0 130.185.74.136:53       0.0.0.0:*                           3489/named      
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           3489/named      
udp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                                3489/named
```

I don't know why i did not get any error when use `service start`!